# Laravel: Move model attributes position

Tags: php, laravel

I was used relationships in my model and it's working fine but the sort of output array is wrong.I want to move `created_at` and `updated_at` in the end of the array

The output is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test home",
    "created_at": "2022-01-01T15:27:31.000000Z", <---------
    "updated_at": "2022-01-01T15:27:31.000000Z", <---------
    "doors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "home_id": 1,
            "button_count": 2,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

But it's should be:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test home",
    "doors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "home_id": 1,
            "button_count": 2,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2022-01-01T15:27:31.000000Z", <---------
    "updated_at": "2022-01-01T15:27:31.000000Z"  <---------
}
```

And it's my model class:

```
class Home extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "homes";
    protected $hidden = ["device_id"];
    protected $with = ["doors"];

    public function device(){
        return $this->hasOne(Device::class,"id","device_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason btw? the order doesn't matter ... use a transformer of some sort, like an ApiResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest approach if you are building an API (not sure if your scenario) is by using Resources where you can format the response as you wish. This is also helpful for being sure that Models will be returned with the same structure in all endpoints.

Assuming you want to fetch all homes with their devices, you can create a `DeviceResource` for returning specific device properties

```
PHP artisan make:resource DeviceResource
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class DeviceResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'home_id' => $this->home_id,
            'button_count' => $this->button_count,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
    }
}
```

Then create a `HomeResource` which will includes `DeviceResource`

```
PHP artisan make:resource HomeResource
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class HomeResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'devices' => DeviceResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('devices')),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
    }
}
```

Then you just return the `HomeResource` collection in your controller

```
$homes = Home::with('devices')->get();
$response = HomeResource::collection($homes);

return $response;
```

Or in case you want to return only 1 `Home`...

```
$home = Home::with('devices')->findOrFail($home_id);
$response = new HomeResource($home);

return $response;
```

Be aware that if you don't load `devices` relationships, the `HomeResource` won't return the `devices` property.